# how do you get cassandra cluster metadata info when using vertx-cassandra-client?

Tags: java, cassandra, vert.x

Using normal cassandra java client, is easy to get cluster metadata, but how to do it when using vert.x cassandra client?

On vert.x you initialise and use a CassandraClient with no access to cluster.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

When you are defining CassandraClientOptions to use with your CassandraClient, the options class has a handler to reference the cluster for the future:

```
CassandraClientOptions options = new CassandraClientOptions()
                    .addContactPoint(node == null ? "127.0.0.1" : node).setPort(port);
options.dataStaxClusterBuilder().withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
                    .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setFetchSize(8000)).withSocketOptions(socketOptions)
                    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
                    // .withCredentials(username, password)
                    .build();
 //your opportunity to get a handle for cluster
cluster = options.dataStaxClusterBuilder().build();
client = CassandraClient.createNonShared(vertx, options);
cluster.getMetadata().....
```

//